# How to run actions in QGIS web client?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

In practice the QGIS web client will be a companion to an existing cloud database with a portal and forms.  My intent is to run 'actions' (like in QGIS) where clicking on a feature launches the portal and the associated form.  Vice versa, clicking on a link in the database form will launch the web client and zoom to the feature.

Is this possible?  Any hints on how to make this happen in Web Client or the effort involved to make it possible?

Thanks!